# Rotate telephone unselect my item in list View

Tags: java, android

When I rotated a phone a selected item is unselected in list view. This is my adapter. I just want to change a color from selected item (it is a single choose only) and when I rotate a phone I want to see what I select. Now when I rotate a phone a I don't see a select item.

```
public class MainAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<RowEntity> rowEntities;

    public MainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowEntity> rowEntities) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowEntities = rowEntities;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowEntities.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowEntities.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_row_holder, null);
            holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            holder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_distance);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        RowEntity rowEntity = rowEntities.get(position);

        if(rowEntity != null){
            holder.address.setText(rowEntity.getAddress());
            holder.address.setText(rowEntity.getAddress());
            holder.distance.setText(rowEntity.getDistance() +"");
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView address;
        TextView distance;
        TextView description;
        TextView name;
    }
}
```

And this is my listView on layout :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/background_listview"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomPanel" />
```

This is background_listview.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white_background"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/primary_color"
        android:state_focused="false" />
</selector>
```

And I add this on manifest :

```
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

when I rotate a phone onCreate is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your activity launchMode to `singleTop`:

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleTop" >
</activity>
```

and override onNewIntent:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    //setIntent(intent);
}
```

This will reuse the activity from the stack of activities.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Android reloads the layout (basically recreates it on configuration changes. In your case it's the rotation of the screen.

You can prevent android from doing this by applying the following attribute in your manifest.xml under the activity where this problem happens

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This tells android you want to handle configuration changes yourself.